# Prove $ \|u\|_{L^q(\Bbb{R}^n)}\le \|(\Delta +z) u\|_{L^p(\Bbb{R}^n)} $ when $|z|\le 1$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces, harmonic-analysis

I was trying to prove the following estimate

$$ \|u\|_{L^q(\Bbb{R}^n)}\le \|(\Delta +z) u\|_{L^p(\Bbb{R}^n)} \tag{*}$$
For all $z\in \Bbb{C}$,all $u\in C^\infty_c(\Bbb{R}^n)$,with $n\ge 3,$ and $\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{q} = \frac{2}{n}$ and $\frac{n+1}{2n} <\frac{1}{p}<\frac{n+3}{2n}$.

Our professor told us we can find the solution in Koenig, Ruiz, Sogge 1987 paper [here](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/duke-mathematical-journal/volume-55/issue-2/Uniform-Sobolev-inequalities-and-unique-continuation-for-second-order-constant/10.1215/S0012-7094-87-05518-9.short).

Assume for now I can prove the case when $|z|\ge 1$,the paper says the case when $|z|\le 1$ can be deduced from the case when $|z|\ge 1$.(Before theorem 2.3).

I can't figure out how to deduce $|z|\le1$?

Comment: Try replacing $u(x)$ by $u_\lambda(x):= u(\lambda x)$ so that you can replace $z$ by $\lambda^2z$; take $\lambda$ large. Use $1/p - 1/q = 2/n$.

Comment: thank you,I got it